# .NET Avoid exception middleware to handle specific exception (stripe)

Tags: c#, .net, error-handling, stripe-payments, try-catch

**The Problem**

I have a method that essentially assigns an account a specific role, and then creates a Stripe account for the user. The issue is if the Stripe method throws an exception, the middleware returns it to the client right away. Instead, I need the Stripe method to throw the exception to where it was originally called from and catch it there, in order to revert any changes I made to the user.

Here is what I have for the Stripe method:

```
    public async Task<Account> CreateStripeAccount(CreateStripeAccountDto createAccount, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var options = new AccountCreateOptions
        {
            ...
        };

        var service = new AccountService();
        try
        {
            var stripeAccount = await service.CreateAsync(options, null, cancellationToken);
            return stripeAccount;
        }
        catch (StripeException ex)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation($"Exception from stripe: {ex.Message}");
            throw;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation($"Exception when creating a stripe account: {ex.Message}");
            throw;
        }
        
    }
```

Here is the method where I originally called it from (where I need to catch the StripeException):

```
    public async Task<string> CreateStore(CreateStoreDto createStore, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        // assign user role
        _userManager.AssignRole(...);
        // create stripe account

        var createStripeAccountDto = new CreateStripeAccountDto(...);

        try
        {
            // HERE IS WHERE I'M CALLING IT FROM
            var stripeAccount = await _stripeService.CreateStripeAccount(createStripeAccountDto, cancellationToken);
            var stripeAccountLink = await _stripeService.GenerateAccountLink(stripeAccount.Id, cancellationToken);
        
            ....

            return stripeAccountLink.Url;
        }
        catch (StripeException ex)
        {
            // Need to revert user changes if a stripe exception occurs
            throw;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Need to revert changes if exception occurs

            _logger.LogError($"...");
            throw;
        }
    }
```

But what's instead happening is in the CreateStripeAccount method, if a StripeException occurs, it goes straight to the middleware and I can't revert my changes.

How can I prevent this from happening and instead throw the exception to where it was originally called from?